# IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@] bound to thread [] - sometimes after uploading a file

Tags: hibernate, grails

1 of 10 times when I'm trying to upload a file Grails throws an exception. How can I solve it? I don't think that the problem with uploading.

---

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@a8008e] bound to thread [http-8080-6]
    at com.gramant.web.PatchedGrailsPageFilter.doFilter(PatchedGrailsPageFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.shiro.grails.SavedRequestFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestFilter.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by commenting custom line `/*GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(SpringUtils.ctx)*/`